# Type of number in overloading

Tags: java

There are two methods both are overloaded methods

```
int add(int a, int b)
```

And

```
int add(long a, long b)
```

And if I call

```
add(3,4)
```

Which method will be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

int add() will be called:

**Method Overloading:** If a class have multiple methods by same name but different parameters, it is known as Method Overloading. In java, Methood Overloading is not possible by changing the return type of the method..

See The output of this code : 
Code:

```
public class MethodOverload {

    static void add(int a, int b) {

        System.out.println("Call 1:" + (a + b));
    }

    static void add(Long a, Long b) {

        System.out.println("Call 2:" + (a + b));
    }

    static void add(Long a, int b) {

        System.out.println("Call 3 :" + (a + b));
    }

    static void add(int a, long b) {

        System.out.println("Call 4 :" + (a + b));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        add(3, 4);
        add(3L, 4L);
        add(3L,4);
        add(3, 4L);

   }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Call 1:7  
Call 2:7  
Call 3 :7  
Call 4 :7
```

[Reference link](http://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-in-java)

Answer (score 6):

`int add(int a, int b)` will be called, since `3` and `4` are both of type `int`, so the compiler prefers the method that does not require a widening cast. Since a method with parameter types matching the parametes exists, it is chosen.

If at least one parameter is of type `long`,

```
int add(long a, long b)
```

would be chosen instead, since a cast from `long` to `int` needs to be done explicitly.

```
add(3, 4L); // calls add(long, long)
add(3, (int) 4L); // calls add(int, int) (explicit cast long -> int)
```

In general you could select the argument type that uses the most bits in this case and select the method based on this information:

If it's `long`, then `add(long, long)` will be called. Otherwise `add(int, int)` is used.

The following calls use `add(int, int)`

```
add('a', 'b'); // most bits: char (assignable to int)
add((short)1, (byte)2);  // most bits: short (assignable to int)
```

the following calls use `add(long, long)`

```
add('a', (long)'b'); // most bits: long (not assignable to int)
add((long)1, (byte)2); // most bits: long (not assignable to int)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you call `add(3,4)`

`int add(int a, int b)` will be called because `1` and `3` are int by default (it is in the specification). 
So if you want another number type, the relevant suffix should be added in the declaration of the value. For example `1L` and `3L` use long types.

So if you call `add(3L,4L)`, `int add(long a, long b)` will be called.

---

**Integer Literals**

> An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l;
>   otherwise it is of type int. It is recommended that you use the upper
>   case letter L because the lower case letter l is hard to distinguish
>   from the digit 1.

More details in Oracle documentation on data types [here](http://Integer%20Literals%20%20An%20integer%20literal%20is%20of%20type%20long%20if%20it%20ends%20with%20the%20letter%20L%20or%20l;%20otherwise%20it%20is%20of%20type%20int.%20It%20is%20recommended%20that%20you%20use%20the%20upper%20case%20letter%20L%20because%20the%20lower%20case%20letter%20l%20is%20hard%20to%20distinguish%20from%20the%20digit%201.)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

It will call the method which have more specific to arguments parameters.

Ex.

```
int add(int a, int b) {
return a+b;
}

int add(long a, long b) {
return a+b;
}
```

if u call `int a = add(3,4)` its call **first method**

& if u call

```
long a=3;
int c;
c = add(a,a);
c = add(a,1);
c = add(1,a);
c = add(3L,4L);
```

its call **second one**.